# Kendo upload mvc in ie - no progress bar or percentage

Tags: file-upload, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

I'm using MVC with Kendo controls.

```
{ 
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("fileuploaddocs")
        .Multiple(true)
        .ShowFileList(true)
        .Events(events => events.Select("fileuploaddocs_onSelect"))
            .Events(events => events.Upload("fileuploaddocs_onUpload"))
            .Events(events => events.Success("fileuploaddocs_onSuccess"))
            .Events(events => events.Error("fileuploaddocs_onError")
            .Async(async => async
                .Save("Save", "Document")
                .Remove("Remove", "Document")
            .AutoUpload(true)
        )
    )
```

In every browser, except IE, there is a dynamically added progress bar and percentage span. How can I force to display progress bar or percentage span in IE?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which IE version you use so I assume it may be 8, 9 or older.

You progress bar is missing because Kendo Upload uses HMTL5 File API to track progress of file upload. That is why it is visible in modern browsers like Chrome, Firefox which utilize HTML5. In older IE versions, a fallback method is used with iframe uploading, which unfortunately does not support progressbar feature.

According to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx File API support was added in IE 10 so it should work there. But this is IE so you never know :)

I've run a test on http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/async with my IE8 and the progressbar is not working as expected.

So to sum up. Even if you force progressbar display, it will still go from 0% to 100% in one go after the upload is complete and will not show the real progress.